# Is there a reason to ask for password only after typing login?

Tags: login, web, password

I saw that there is a recent trend in splitting the sign-in step into two: login followed by password (rather than in a single stage). That is, the flow is: `[type username] -> [confirm] -> [type password] -> [confirm]`.

For example, here is how does it work at Amazon and DocuSign:

[image]
[image]

Personally, I find this UI annoying, as it adds one more unnecessary step. Even worse, it makes it harder to use password managers (such as 1Password).

So, what are the reasons for the username/password step split?

Comment: Does not *answer*, but the question is the same. Feel free to mark this one as a duplicate (didn't find it before).

There are some answers in
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160692/why-do-some-sites-ask-for-username-email-and-password-on-two-separate-screens, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85160/is-having-the-username-and-password-fields-on-different-pages-more-secure, as posted by @f222.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know this is mainly a server side reason.

(Not all servers can handle an e-mail and they use the first page to find on which server you should be authenticated).

I saw a similar question on another stackexchange (maybe superuser or serverfault, I can't find it) not long ago which describes more precisely the reasons.

EDIt: I found the question I was thinking of : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257407/is-it-more-secure-to-ask-only-for-the-username-before-the-password

Answer (score 0):

- A way of showing the user doesn't exist in the database
- Warning the typed text is wrong
- In this situation it is not necessary to type a password
- Instead of going to the second window, an alert appears

[image]

Comment: All of these things are solved by one-step log-in. The arguments you provided optimize (a bit) the case of an error, at cost of the (much more common) no-error scenario.

Comment: In fact it does not optimise anything as all these checks can be performed with javascript and thus would raise an error before a person would enter a password.